# How to pass information from a form into a function in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a login model with the following login function:

```
  login() {
    console.log("Hello. It's Me")
    axios.post('https://crossorigin.me/http://requestb.in/w21igbw2', {
      firstName: 'Fred',
      lastName: 'Flintstone'
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      //this.setState({ showModal: false });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

this is working fine, so how I do change this to send the actual data from the login form instead of just the hardcoded info in the function.  The input in the login model this is what the full form looks like:

```
          <form>
            <FormGroup >
              <Row>
                <Col md={12}>
                  <input className="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 top-space fat-input" placeholder="Email"/>
                  <input className="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 top-space fat-input" placeholder="Password"/>
                </Col>
              </Row>
              <Row className='top-space'>
                <Col md={5} mdOffset={1}>
                  <Checkbox className="checkbox-login"> Remember Me </Checkbox>
                </Col>
                <Col md={6} className='forgot-password'>
                  <a href="">Forgot Password</a>
                </Col>
              </Row>
              <Row className='top-space'>
                <Col md={10} mdOffset={1}>
                  <Button onClick={this.login} bsStyle="btn btn-black btn-block">Login</Button>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </FormGroup>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of inputs in you state and when you fire API read the values from the state.

```
constructor(){
    super()
  this.state = {
     email : null,
     password : null,
  }

  onChangeEmail(){
    this.setState({email: e.target.value});
  }

  onChangePassword(){
   this.setState({password: e.target.value});
  }

  login(){
        //api call with state values for id and pass
  }

  render(){
    <form>
            <FormGroup >
              <Row>
                <Col md={12}>
                  <input className="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 top-space fat-input" placeholder="Email" onChange={this.onChangeEmail}/>
                  <input className="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 top-space fat-input" placeholder="Password" onChange={this.onChangePassword}/>
                </Col>
              </Row>
              <Row className='top-space'>
                <Col md={5} mdOffset={1}>
                  <Checkbox className="checkbox-login"> Remember Me </Checkbox>
                </Col>
                <Col md={6} className='forgot-password'>
                  <a href="">Forgot Password</a>
                </Col>
              </Row>
              <Row className='top-space'>
                <Col md={10} mdOffset={1}>
                  <Button onClick={this.login} bsStyle="btn btn-black btn-block">Login</Button>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </FormGroup>
          </form>
  }
}
```

**P.S:** I would strongly suggest using redux with react and using **redux-form** to handle you forms. It has been the best way I have found till now to handle forms in react-redux app. You can check it out [here](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form).